# Requests package python is not imported

Tags: python, python-requests

I have installed requests package on my mac (10.8) as any other with `pip`.

I can see it under `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages`.

However when I `import requests` in a python script I get a terminal error:
`ImportError: No module named requests` as if it's not installed.

Easy install say it is installed as well:

```
$ easy_install requests
Searching for requests
Best match: requests 1.2.3
Adding requests 1.2.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages
Processing dependencies for requests
Finished processing dependencies for requests
```

The only error I could locate was when upgrading with pip:

```
$ pip install requests --upgrade
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Real name of requirement requests is requests
  Downloading requests-1.2.3.tar.gz (348Kb): 348Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests

Installing collected packages: requests
  Found existing installation: requests 1.2.3
    Uninstalling requests:
      Successfully uninstalled requests
  Running setup.py install for requests

      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/ntlmpool.py", line 38
        """
         ^
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 130-132: truncated \uXXXX escape

Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...
```

Some ideas why it cannot be imported? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your script is running under Python 3.2 and not Apple's pre-installed 2.7, or some other version?

Comment: @abarnert like that `$ python3 /Users/me/Desktop/script.py` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `urllib3`. Looking at the source, starting at line 33 of the file that raised the error:

```
def __init__(self, user, pw, authurl, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    authurl is a random URL on the server that is protected by NTLM.
    user is the Windows user, probably in the DOMAIN\username format.
    pw is the password for the user.
    """
```

That `\u` in the middle of the string is illegal. I don't get this error from just `import requests` or even `import requests.packages.urllib3`, but if I `import requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.ntlmpool`, I get it too.

I don't know why it's automatically importing `ntlmpool` for you, but that's not important; it's definitely a bug.

---

The bug was fixed in `urllib` in [change 1f7f39cb](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/commit/1f7f39cb53b79f975e559c8f7ae48ce056417044) on 2013-05-22, and merged to `requests` in [change 2ed976ea](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/commit/2ed976ea7147a9d0c18998e02b16d691b6798a3e) on 2013-06-08 as part of [issue 1412](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1412). But it's still present in the 1.2.3 release, which is the latest version [on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) as of 2013-07-05. You can find further information in [issue 1416](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1416), which was closed fixed with the comment "The fix should be out fairly soon."

So, you have three choices:

- Wait for 1.2.4.
- `pip install git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests` to install the top-of-tree code off github instead of the last official release.
- Edit your local copy of `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/ntlmpool.py` to escape the backslash on line 38.

The code should look like this:

```
def __init__(self, user, pw, authurl, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    authurl is a random URL on the server that is protected by NTLM.
    user is the Windows user, probably in the DOMAIN\\username format.
    pw is the password for the user.
    """
```

Comment: @abamert Thanks, I just changed that file. Now the reason why it's not importing it is probably that I have messed up some packages with different python version. About time to use virtual enviroments..

Comment: The Syntax Error you've revealed is harmless in almost every case, so shouldn't affect the import. =)

Comment: This is an old post, but I'm still getting this problem in Python 37. Any updates on this? I don't see a packages folder in the requests folder.